# how to disable the help information when we hover the cursor on a variable/function in spyder

Tags: spyder

I want to disable the help information that shows up when my cursor is on a function or a variable. how can I do this?

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/A8kpf.png)

Comment: do you mean "cursor" instead of "coarser"?

Comment: @con yes, sorry about that